# Multiple Matching Data returns values

Tags: excel, function

2 large data sets which one is for import into program (worksheet 2), worksheet 2 is for easy modifications.

what formula can be used to copy qty's in worksheet 2 to qty's in worksheet 1 if code 1 and code 2 ranges match.

WORKSHEET 1

```
code 1  Description      code 2 QTY
ITEM1   EXAMPLE          100    
ITEM1   EXAMPLE          200    
ITEM1   EXAMPLE          A  
ITEM1   EXAMPLE          B  
ITEM1   EXAMPLE          C
```

WORKSHEET 2

```
CODE 2  100 200 A   B   C   D
CODE 1  Description                                                                 
ITEM 1  EXAMPLE QTY   20    25  50  100 2   35
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

In D5 of WORKSHEET 1 and copied down to suit please try:

```
=VLOOKUP(A5,'WORKSHEET 2'!A:I,MATCH(C5,'WORKSHEET 2'!A$17:I$17,0))
```

This makes some assumptions about what else may be in your two worksheets and where but hopefull you can adjust, if necessary.